# App is not active. App is not accessible right now. Facebook Login issue React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, facebook-login

Currently facing this is issue while adding facebook login to app in react native

i am using

```
react-native-fbnext@9.0.0
```

[image: Facebook Login Error]

Comment: That appears to be an issue with your app configuration, so check the app dashboard for the app's current status.

Comment: @CBroe I think, Facebook changed something or a problem with Facebook's OpenID. I see this error on other platform, too. It's new

Answer (score 12):

that's probably not the suggestion you are expecting. But do yourself and your users a favor and remove facebook from your apps. Facebook is disrespecting developers and without any notice keep changing things, not respecting user rights; injecting scripts etc. Especially on IOS, you will have many issues with apple. I have just came to this post because I recognized myself that facebook login isnt working because my app was turned into Development mode, i dont know why and never got any notice from Facebook. This is not the first time Facebook does something like that. I had already in my mind to remove facebook for user rights and finally this triggered. All you need is a username-password login, if you want google login, it is ok at least for developers aspect. they inform you with the changes in advance.
Dont make your app depends on facebook, you will surely regret. There are many posts about if you google.

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to log in with the same account on your phone as well as the developer account when you're in development mode.
2. Make sure you've entered a privacy policy URL.
3. If your development mode is disabled for some reason, it would probably be the cause of your privacy policy URL OR It will fix after you publish your app on Play Store.

Answer (score 2):

If your mode is set to development,

1. try login with test users from the facebook developer account
2. Inside your device logout with any other fb account if it is there.
3. Follow the quickstart guide in facebook sdk properly.

Then it will ask for facebook login

Answer (score 1):

I used to have an error like this with IOS. My solution is check config key FacebookSDK in file **Info.plist** *ios/name_project/Info.plist*. Make sure that is correct with tutorial **step 2** of FB: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

Answer (score 1):

i just fount the solution of that probem, you need to login with the same facbook account which you login in the facebook developer account
syed06411@gmail.com this person help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution,
For me turning the app into development mode was the solution.

**Just keep in mind these following things and you will not run into this problem.**

1. Create app in business category.
2. Add a privacy policy.
3. Switch to live mode from development.

Thank you hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Brother just turn on your app status(live) from your facebook developer account After filling all your information.

And Also use latest dependency. I've added below dependency in my project and it's working.

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[8,9)'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. After changing the App Mode to Live, it's working perfectly.

Here's how you can change the App Mode to Live:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Error** : This error occurs when a user does not have the necessary access to perform certain actions. It commonly happens in development mode, where only administrators, developers, and test users are allowed to log in.

**Simple-Solution** : Login with same account which is used for [Facebook-Developer-Console](https://developers.facebook.com).

**Alternative-Solution** :

- Login into [Facebook-Developer-Console](https://developers.facebook.com)
- Select the specific app you are working on,
- In App Dashboard, navigate to **App-Roles => Roles**
- Add the user as Administrator, Developer or Test-user
- This will grant the permission for accessing the App

**Note: When adding a new user with any of the above roles, their status will initially be set as pending. To activate the user and allow them access, they need to log in to the  [Facebook-Developer-Console](https://developers.facebook.com) and accept the request**

[image]